# SomeApp "is never used"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Below in the image 1 you can see I created a Kotlin class that extends from the Application() class: 
[image: screenshot from Android Studio 3.1.2]

I also added the necessary stuff in my Manifest file as you can see in the next image: [image: Manifest file]

However I can't figure out why Android Studio maintains that I am NOT using my Class at all! It is underlined and grayed out and on mouse over you see the message "Class XZY is never used."

The same behavior I noticed in Versions of Android Studio different from my current one, which is 3.1.2.
Of note might be that if I create the same class in Java, Android Studio functions as it should and knows that I use the class if I mention it in my Manifest file.
Any ideas how to convince the Android Studio that I am actually using this class?

Comment: have you tried a rebuild?

Comment: Have added <activity... /> tag after <application... /> .? In your image it's not clear .

Comment: If you see log message in your logcat that onCreate was called, then file a bug on AS issue tracker.

Comment: @Danger: <activity> tag comes later on down (as MainActivity), since this class is NOT an Activity but an Application class.

Comment: @NazarK: OnCreate is called and the app is running as it should. The problem is only in the AS

Comment: I created the bug report on AS issue tracker

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Of course. It's exactly the same in any of the projects. It's not like this is an exception.

Comment: Do your package names match?

Comment: @gtcompscientist Yes of course. I have send the bug report to AS deveopers and I believe they will fix it soon

Comment: @Hoornet did you fix this?

Comment: @grant 
No... In Android Studio 3.3.1 it is still the same!
I can CLICK on the class and be brought to the right place in Manifest, but editor still says, that "class XYZ is never used"

Comment: Has this been solved? I'm finding the same issue now

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Android Studio. Here is a [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74514347) to Google Issue Tracker (requires Google account).
It was reported there by a few users in March 2018 and got little attention from Google staff ever since.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer on stackoverflow. Please read this article on [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), especially the part: `Provide context for links`. Good luck!

Comment: @NickM_RG :  yeah. I believe it was my own report that was included ... :)

Answer (score 1):

That is bug and it's not yet solved what i did was adding this line before the class

```
@Suppress("unused")
```

Comment: 2 years and 9 months ago I reported this bug to Google...

Comment: Best solution, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select **Invalidate Caches/Restart** from menu File tab.

Comment: Tried this and it did not help on latest Android Studio.